# How to get component model ids of a composed model (azure - form recognizer)?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-form-recognizer

I'm trying to get all custom models from a form recognizer and copy/delete some of them.
I have a lot of composed models so I don't want to delete the collection that is used to create these composed models.
This is the code where i get all models :

```
    private static void GetModelsInfo()
    {
        FormTrainingClient client = new FormTrainingClient(new Uri(FORM_RECOGNIZER_URL), new AzureKeyCredential(FORM_RECOGNIZER_KEY));

        // List the models currently stored in the account.
        Pageable<CustomFormModelInfo> models = client.GetCustomModels();
        
        var list = models.ToList<CustomFormModelInfo>();

    }
```

I can tell if the model is composed by checking the property [IsComposedModel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/API/azure.ai.formrecognizer.training.customformmodelproperties.iscomposedmodel?view=azure-dotnet-preview)

In the form recognizer studio, I can double-click the composed model and I can see all the component models

[image]
[image]

This is exactly what I'm trying to do, but I'm writing a function to do it for me.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can get Compose models details by referring to DocumentModelComposeOperationDetails in this github link code - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/formrecognizer/Azure.AI.FormRecognizer/samples/Sample_GetAndListOperations.md